# Specifically increase an ID value depending on A Foreign Key

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have two database tables; one named Mould, other one named MeasResult.
Mould table has MID as Primary key and MeasResult table has a Foreign Key named MoldID that references MID.
I am logging measurement to MeasResult table using this Foreign key.
MeasResult table also has a MeasID column that keeps track of measurement insert count. For every measurement i am logging 50 rows of data.
What i need to is that i need to increase this MeasID value by 1 every time a new measurement is logged **with minding MoldID (Foreign Key in the table)**.

My current code doesn't mind the Foreign Key, it is just increases MeasResult value by one for every measurement log.

```
using (LinqDataClassesDataContext dataContext = new 
LinqDataClassesDataContext())
            {
                var measid = dataContext.MeasResults.Select(a => 
a.MeasId).Where(p => p != null).Max() + 1;

                string id = ""; string plane = ""; int pos = 0; int dist = 0; double apert = 0;

                id = comboBMouldID.SelectedValue.ToString();
                plane = comboBSurface.SelectedItem.ToString();
                pos = Convert.ToInt32(txtTravelPos.Text);

                for (int i = 0; i < daGridMeas.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    dist = Convert.ToInt32(daGridMeas.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
                    apert = Convert.ToDouble(daGridMeas.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString());

                    var st = new MeasResult();
                    {
                        st.MoldID = id;
                        st.Plane = plane;
                        st.Postn = pos;
                        st.Distnc = dist;
                        st.Apert = apert;
                        st.MeasId = measid;
                        st.Date = DateTime.Now;
                    };

                    dataContext.MeasResults.InsertOnSubmit(st);
                    dataContext.SubmitChanges();
                }
```

How can i change the code so it would increase MeasID by 1 for every measurement taken for specific MoldID?

Comment: Is there any reason why you dont set the column to auto increment by 1 in the database? Looks like you insert into the MeasResult only when the measurement happens anyway.

Comment: So what you need is that MeasID should be equal to the number of previously created MeasResult records that have the same MoldID? Do I understand your question correctly?

Comment: @iSpain17 Yes exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Currently your code is grabbing all the MeasId and incrementing the max value. Try putting a where filter prior to the select method.

```
var measid = dataContext.MeasResults.Where(mr => mr.MoldID == id).Select(a => a.MeasId).Max() + 1;
```

The idea here, is instead of selecting the maximum MeasId value from the entire table, you will first filter out all but the measurements for the MoldID that you are recording.

---

```
string id = ""; string plane = ""; int pos = 0; int dist = 0; double apert = 0;

id = comboBMouldID.SelectedValue.ToString();
plane = comboBSurface.SelectedItem.ToString();
pos = Convert.ToInt32(txtTravelPos.Text);

var tmpRecord = dataContext.MeasResults.Where(mr => mr.MoldID == id).OrderByDescending(mr => mr.MeasId).FirstOrDefault();
int measid = tmpRecord != null ? tmpRecord.MeasId + 1 : 1;

...
```

The tmpRecord statement filters the MeasResults table for all records with MoldID equaling the selected id. Then we sort them in descending order using the MeasId as our sort column. Finally, we take the top record or a null record if none exists. The second line first checks that the record isn't null, then it will take the MeasId of that record and increment it by one. If the record is null then we will assign the value of 1.

Comment: I copy-pasted to editor and there is an error `The name 'x' does not exist in the current context.`

Comment: Ah, my bad. please move the ```measid``` statement after the line you assign the value to ```id```.

Comment: MeasID is `int` and cannot be null value. `.Where(p => p != null)` this part only there to confirm it is not null.

Comment: I had meant to add in a comment mentioning substituting 'x' with the MoldID variable in the method call. Then I noticed that you already had a statement assigning it a value from a gui element.

Comment: Yes. how about that? `id` assignment is done in runtime.

Comment: What is the type of MoldID?

Comment: MoldId is nvarchar.

Comment: iSpain17's answer looks to be better. It will handle the condition of nulls, and no existing measurements for a MoldID. My suggestion would be to move the statement after line where ```id``` is assigned a value, and then change the ```comboMouldID.SelectedValue.ToString()``` to ```id```.

Comment: Should I leave my answer, edit it, or just remove it. Unsure of the expectation here.

Comment: iSpain17's suggestion gives compiler error and i couldn't understand yours clearly. Can you please share it as code piece?

Comment: iSpain17's approach cannot work for me because for every measurement i am logging around 50 rows of data. I missed to mention it in the question. Sorry about that.

Comment: Try the edit. The two lines at the end should check that we have a record with the maximum MeasID value, and that it is not null. Then it will increment the value or make it a 0. Please note that you will be removing the first measid assignment.

Comment: This is working. Thank you. But it starts from 0. is it possible to make it start from 1? or would it make any difference?

Comment: You are welcome. I am glad it helped. I added an explanation of what the two lines did as well.

Answer (score 0):

Then it should be pretty simple based on your answer.

Calculate the existing number of records with this MoldID:

```
var NumberOfPreviousMeasurements = dataContext.MeasResults.Where(m => m.MoldId == comboMouldID.SelectedValue.ToString()).Count();
```

And then assign this value as the MeasId of the new record.
Shouldn't this suffice?

Comment: Compiler gives an error for this; `Cannot assign method group to an implicitly-typed variable`

Comment: Yes, I forgot the () and the end of Count, sorry :)

Comment: This approach didn't work because i am logging several results for every measurement. for example for every measurement 50 rows added to table. So this function calculates the row quantity and adds it to next measurement. I am sorry i missed this detail in the question

Comment: Then you could just add to your .Where clause: `.Where(p => p!= null && p.MoldID == comboBMouldID.SelectedValue.ToString())`

Comment: `The p doesn't exist in current content` error in compiler

Comment: Because you are not putting it in the right place. I used `p` to signal that you should put it in the `.Where()` method which has the `p` variable inside. Did you write the code that you posted?